# Instantiate chaincode successful but chaincode doesn't appear

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am running Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.x, and release-1.4 of `fabric-sdk-java`. I am trying to use the following code to instantiate a chaincode:

```
InstantiateProposalRequest instantiateProposalRequest = client.newInstantiationProposalRequest();
instantiateProposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(180000);
instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeID(buildChaincodeID(name, version, path));
instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeLanguage(Type.JAVA);
instantiateProposalRequest.setFcn("init");
instantiateProposalRequest.setArgs(new String[] {""});
Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendInstantiationProposal(instantiateProposalRequest);
```

The instantiation seemed successful, but I don't see it listed when I check with `peer chaincode list --instantiated -C deconeb-channel`.

The following log is from the point I execute the code (with `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG:msp=info:gossip=info`):

```
[root@vmdev2 createchannel]# docker logs $(docker ps -aqf name=fabric_peer1) -n 0 -f
... [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 22d2 Entering: request from 192.168.50.126:3280
... [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 22d3 ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc003725b30
... [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 22d4 validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 22d5 begin
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 22d6 creator is &{myMSP 0167d1f59420e22fb1032bc6a17b528414378511c23a07719d2b364842f862a7}
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 22d7 creator is valid
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 22d8 exits successfully
... [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 22d9 validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc001fb47e0, header 0xc0036cc870
... [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 22da validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"cscc"
... [endorser] preProcess -> DEBU 22db [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] processing txid: db2d2e4fef0b7cb0889fe6d0258b2f424426c180be62457c2f2cf5ec00bdd96c
... [fsblkstorage] retrieveTransactionByID -> DEBU 22dc retrieveTransactionByID() - txId = [db2d2e4fef0b7cb0889fe6d0258b2f424426c180be62457c2f2cf5ec00bdd96c]
... [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 22dd [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc"
... [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 22de [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc"
... [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 22df Entry
... [cscc] Invoke -> DEBU 22e0 Invoke function: GetConfigBlock
... [aclmgmt] CheckACL -> DEBU 22e1 acl policy not found in config for resource cscc/GetConfigBlock
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22e2 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers ==
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22e3 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22e4 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers ==
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 22e5 0xc00059ec70 gate 1638419940859552678 evaluation starts
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22e6 0xc00059ec70 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22e7 0xc00059ec70 processing identity 0 with bytes of 115a2d0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22e8 0xc00059ec70 principal matched by identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22e9 0xc00059ec70 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22ea 0xc00059ec70 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22eb 0xc00059ec70 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22ec 0xc00059ec70 principal evaluation fails
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22ed 0xc00059ec70 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22ee 0xc00059ec70 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 22ef 0xc00059ec70 principal evaluation fails
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 22f0 0xc00059ec70 gate 1638419940859552678 evaluation succeeds
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22f1 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22f2 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22f3 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 22f4 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers
... [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 22f5 [db2d2e4f] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
... [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 22f6 [db2d2e4f] notifying Txid:db2d2e4fef0b7cb0889fe6d0258b2f424426c180be62457c2f2cf5ec00bdd96c, channelID:deconeb-channel
... [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 22f7 Exit
... [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 22f8 [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Exit chaincode: name:"cscc"  (1ms)
... [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 22f9 [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Exit
... [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 22fa [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Entry chaincode: name:"cscc"
... [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 22fb [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] escc for chaincode name:"cscc"  is escc
... [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 22fc Entering endorsement for {plugin: escc, channel: deconeb-channel, tx: db2d2e4fef0b7cb0889fe6d0258b2f424426c180be62457c2f2cf5ec00bdd96c, chaincode: cscc}
... [endorser] EndorseWithPlugin -> DEBU 22fd Exiting {plugin: escc, channel: deconeb-channel, tx: db2d2e4fef0b7cb0889fe6d0258b2f424426c180be62457c2f2cf5ec00bdd96c, chaincode: cscc}
... [endorser] endorseProposal -> DEBU 22fe [deconeb-channel][db2d2e4f] Exit
... [endorser] func1 -> DEBU 22ff Exit: request from 192.168.50.126:3280
... [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 2300 unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=192.168.50.126:3280 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.1014ms
... [common.deliverevents] Deliver -> DEBU 2301 Starting new Deliver handler
... [common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2302 Starting new deliver loop for 192.168.50.126:3285
... [common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 2303 Attempting to read seek info message from 192.168.50.126:3285
... [aclmgmt] CheckACL -> DEBU 2304 acl policy not found in config for resource event/Block
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2305 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers ==
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2306 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2307 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers ==
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2308 0xc00373d130 gate 1638419941422542679 evaluation starts
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2309 0xc00373d130 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230a 0xc00373d130 processing identity 0 with bytes of 115a2d0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230b 0xc00373d130 principal matched by identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230c 0xc00373d130 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230d 0xc00373d130 signed by 1 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230e 0xc00373d130 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 230f 0xc00373d130 principal evaluation fails
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2310 0xc00373d130 signed by 2 principal evaluation starts (used [true])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2311 0xc00373d130 skipping identity 0 because it has already been used
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2312 0xc00373d130 principal evaluation fails
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2313 0xc00373d130 gate 1638419941422542679 evaluation succeeds
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2314 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2315 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/myMSP/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2316 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Readers
... [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2317 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers
... [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> DEBU 2318 [channel: deconeb-channel] Received seekInfo (0xc002fa3a40) start:<newest:<> > stop:<specified:<number:9223372036854775807 > >  from 192.168.50.126:3285
... [fsblkstorage] Next -> DEBU 2319 Initializing block stream for iterator. itr.maxBlockNumAvailable=1
... [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileStream -> DEBU 231a newBlockfileStream(): filePath=[/var/hyperledger/production/ledgersData/chains/chains/deconeb-channel/blockfile_000000], startOffset=[21642]
... [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 231b Remaining bytes=[4671], Going to peek [8] bytes
... [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 231c Returning blockbytes - length=[4669], placementInfo={fileNum=[0], startOffset=[21642], bytesOffset=[21644]}
... [fsblkstorage] nextBlockBytesAndPlacementInfo -> DEBU 231d blockbytes [4669] read from file [0]
... [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> DEBU 231e [channel: deconeb-channel] Delivering block [1] for (0xc002fa3a40) for 192.168.50.126:3285
... [fsblkstorage] waitForBlock -> DEBU 231f Going to wait for newer blocks. maxAvailaBlockNumber=[1], waitForBlockNum=[2]
... [endorser] ProcessProposal -> DEBU 2320 Entering: request from 192.168.50.126:3280
... [protoutils] ValidateProposalMessage -> DEBU 2321 ValidateProposalMessage starts for signed proposal 0xc0033d4fa0
... [protoutils] validateChannelHeader -> DEBU 2322 validateChannelHeader info: header type 3
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 2323 begin
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 2324 creator is &{myMSP 0167d1f59420e22fb1032bc6a17b528414378511c23a07719d2b364842f862a7}
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 2325 creator is valid
... [protoutils] checkSignatureFromCreator -> DEBU 2326 exits successfully
... [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 2327 validateChaincodeProposalMessage starts for proposal 0xc00014d5e0, header 0xc0033d53b0
... [protoutils] validateChaincodeProposalMessage -> DEBU 2328 validateChaincodeProposalMessage info: header extension references chaincode name:"lscc"
... [endorser] preProcess -> DEBU 2329 [deconeb-channel][bc1525c4] processing txid: bc1525c4a55b0d9115df62e094cc5f651a38bd1e037bf0675296f77f489585da
... [fsblkstorage] retrieveTransactionByID -> DEBU 232a retrieveTransactionByID() - txId = [bc1525c4a55b0d9115df62e094cc5f651a38bd1e037bf0675296f77f489585da]
... [lockbasedtxmgr] NewTxSimulator -> DEBU 232b constructing new tx simulator
... [lockbasedtxmgr] newLockBasedTxSimulator -> DEBU 232c constructing new tx simulator txid = [bc1525c4a55b0d9115df62e094cc5f651a38bd1e037bf0675296f77f489585da]
... [endorser] SimulateProposal -> DEBU 232d [deconeb-channel][bc1525c4] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
... [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 232e [deconeb-channel][bc1525c4] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
... [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 232f Entry
... [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 2330 [bc1525c4] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: GET_STATE in state ready
... [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 2331 [bc1525c4] handling GET_STATE from chaincode
... [chaincode] HandleGetState -> DEBU 2332 [bc1525c4] getting state for chaincode lscc, key productOwnership, channel deconeb-channel
... [statecouchdb] GetState -> DEBU 2333 GetState(). ns=lscc, key=productOwnership
... [couchdb] ReadDoc -> DEBU 2334 [deconeb-channel_lscc] Entering ReadDoc()  id=[productOwnership]
... [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 2335 Entering handleRequest()  method=GET  url=http://couchdb1.myorg.com:5984  dbName=deconeb-channel_lscc
... [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 2336 Request URL: http://couchdb1.myorg.com:5984/deconeb-channel_lscc/productOwnership?attachments=true
... [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 2337 HTTP Request: GET /deconeb-channel_lscc/productOwnership?attachments=true HTTP/1.1 | Host: couchdb1.myorg.com:5984 | User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1 | Accept: multipart/related | Authorization: Basic Y291Y2hkYjpjb3VjaGRiMTIz | Accept-Encoding: gzip |  |
... [couchdb] handleRequest -> DEBU 2338 Error handling CouchDB request. Error:not_found,  Status Code:404,  Reason:missing
... [couchdb] ReadDoc -> DEBU 2339 [deconeb-channel_lscc] Document not found (404), returning nil value instead of 404 error
... [chaincode] HandleGetState -> DEBU 233a [bc1525c4] No state associated with key: productOwnership. Sending RESPONSE with an empty payload
... [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 233b [bc1525c4] Completed GET_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 233c 0xc00370e210 gate 1638419941463477320 evaluation starts
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 233d 0xc00370e210 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 233e 0xc00370e210 processing identity 0 with bytes of 115a2d0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 233f 0xc00370e210 principal matched by identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 2340 0xc00370e210 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
... [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 2341 0xc00370e210 gate 1638419941463477320 evaluation succeeds
... [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 2342 [bc1525c4] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: PUT_STATE in state ready
... [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 2343 [bc1525c4] handling PUT_STATE from chaincode
... [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> DEBU 2344 [bc1525c4] Completed PUT_STATE. Sending RESPONSE
... [lscc] putChaincodeCollectionData -> DEBU 2345 No collection configuration specified
... [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 2346 [bc1525c4] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: COMPLETED in state ready
... [chaincode] Notify -> DEBU 2347 [bc1525c4] notifying Txid:bc1525c4a55b0d9115df62e094cc5f651a38bd1e037bf0675296f77f489585da, channelID:deconeb-channel
... [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 2348 Exit
... [chaincode] LaunchConfig -> DEBU 2349 launchConfig: executable:"/root/chaincode-java/start",Args:[/root/chaincode-java/start,--peerAddress,peer1.myorg.com:7052],Envs:[CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info,CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=warning,CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_FORMAT=%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message},CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=productOwnership:1.0,CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true,CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key,CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt,CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt],Files:[/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key /etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt]
... [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 234a start container: productOwnership:1.0
... [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 234b start container with args: /root/chaincode-java/start --peerAddress peer1.myorg.com:7052
... [chaincode] Start -> DEBU 234c start container with env:
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_SHIM=warning
        CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_FORMAT=%{color}%{time:2006-01-02 15:04:05.000 MST} [%{module}] %{shortfunc} -> %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}
        CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=productOwnership:1.0
        CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key
        CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt
        CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt
... [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 234d waiting for container(productOwnership-1.0) lock
... [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 234e got container (productOwnership-1.0) lock
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 234f stopping container id=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 2350 stop container result error="No such container: dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0"
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 2351 killing container id=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 2352 kill container result id=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0 error="No such container: dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0"
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 2353 removing container id=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 2354 remove container result id=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0 error="No such container: dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0"
... [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 2355 create container imageID=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productownership-1.0-8833aa49d3efc325e99f93399c3e02417a6d5a271b81e9013f3095580e89b308 containerID=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [dockercontroller] getDockerHostConfig -> DEBU 2356 docker container hostconfig NetworkMode: devbc
... [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 2357 created container imageID=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productownership-1.0-8833aa49d3efc325e99f93399c3e02417a6d5a271b81e9013f3095580e89b308 containerID=dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 2358 Started container dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0
... [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 2359 container lock deleted(productOwnership-1.0)
... [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 235a waiting for container(productOwnership-1.0) lock
... [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 235b got container (productOwnership-1.0) lock
... [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 235c container lock deleted(productOwnership-1.0)
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 235d Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 235e INFO: <<<<<<<<<<<<<Enviromental options>>>>>>>>>>>>
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 235f Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2360 INFO: CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME: productOwnership:1.0
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2361 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2362 INFO: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2363 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2364 INFO: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED: true
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2365 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2366 INFO: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2367 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2368 INFO: CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2369 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236a INFO: CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236b Dec 02, 2021 4:39:02 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processEnvironmentOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236c INFO: LOGLEVEL: INFO
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236d Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236e INFO: <<<<<<<<<<<<<CommandLine options>>>>>>>>>>>>
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 236f Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2370 INFO: CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME: productOwnership:1.0
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2371 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2372 INFO: CORE_PEER_ADDRESS: peer1.myorg.com:7052
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2373 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2374 INFO: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED: true
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2375 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2376 INFO: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/peer.crt
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2377 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2378 INFO: CORE_TLS_CLIENT_KEY_PATH: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.key
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2379 Dec 02, 2021 4:39:03 AM org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase processCommandLineOptions
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237a INFO: CORE_TLS_CLIENT_CERT_PATH: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/client.crt
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237b org.hyperledger
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237c org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237d org.hyperledger
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237e 04:39:03:119 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase initializeLogging                      Loglevel set to INFO
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 237f 04:39:03:130 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase getChaincodeConfig                     <<<<<<<<<<<<<Properties options>>>>>>>>>>>>
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2380 04:39:03:131 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase getChaincodeConfig                     {CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=productOwnership:1.0, CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.myorg.com}
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2381 04:39:03:136 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.metrics.Metrics initialize                                Metrics disabled
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2382 04:39:03:840 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.ChaincodeBase newChannelBuilder                      ()->Configuring channel connection to peer.peer1.myorg.com:7052 tlsenabled true
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2383 04:39:04:408 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager <init>                   Max Pool Size [TP_MAX_POOL_SIZE]5
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2384 04:39:04:408 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager <init>                   Queue Size [TP_CORE_POOL_SIZE]5000
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2385 04:39:04:413 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager <init>                   Core Pool Size [TP_QUEUE_SIZE]5
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2386 04:39:04:413 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager <init>                   Keep Alive Time [TP_KEEP_ALIVE_MS]5000
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2387 04:39:04:421 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskExecutor <init>                  Thread pool created
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2388 04:39:04:422 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient start                    making the grpc call
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2389 04:39:04:596 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager register                 Registering new chaincode name: "productOwnership:1.0"
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 238a
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 238b 04:39:04:620 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$2 accept                 > sendToPeer
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 238c 04:39:04:636 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.ChaincodeSupportClient$2 accept                 < sendToPeer
... [chaincode.accesscontrol] authenticate -> DEBU 238d Chaincode productOwnership:1.0 's authentication is authorized
... [chaincode] handleMessage -> DEBU 238e [] Fabric side handling ChaincodeMessage of type: REGISTER in state created
... [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 238f Received REGISTER in state created
... [chaincode] Register -> DEBU 2390 registered handler complete for chaincode productOwnership:1.0
... [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 2391 Got REGISTER for chaincodeID = name:"productOwnership:1.0" , sending back REGISTERED
... [chaincode] HandleRegister -> DEBU 2392 Changed state to established for name:"productOwnership:1.0"
... [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU 2393 sending READY for chaincode name:"productOwnership:1.0"
... [chaincode] sendReady -> DEBU 2394 Changed to state ready for chaincode name:"productOwnership:1.0"
... [chaincode] Launch -> DEBU 2395 launch complete
... [chaincode] Execute -> DEBU 2396 Entry
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2397 04:39:05:261 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [        ] {
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2398   "type": "REGISTERED"
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 2399 }
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239a 04:39:05:269 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [        ] Received REGISTERED: moving to established state
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239b 04:39:05:273 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [        ] {
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239c   "type": "READY"
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239d }
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239e 04:39:05:274 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [        ] Received READY: ready for invocations
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 239f 04:39:05:288 FINE    org.hyperledger.fabric.shim.impl.InnvocationTaskManager onChaincodeMessage       [bc1525c4] {
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 23a0   "type": "INIT",
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 23a1   "payload": "CgRpbml0CgA=",
... [peer.chaincode.dev-peer1.myorg.com-productOwnership-1.0] func2 -> INFO 23a2   "txid": "bc1525c4a55b0d9115df62e094cc5f651a38bd1e037bf0675296f77f489585da",
```

I had to truncate the log above to fit post requirements; the full log can be found at https://pastebin.com/XBUtQdwz

I don't see any errors in the log so I'm not sure what the problem is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you see chaincode container on a machine where your peer is running? Instantiating in 1.4 should spawn one. Your logs seem to be fine indeed.

Comment: @MimoKrok I didn't see the chaincode container being spawned

Comment: Interesting, you even have logs from it. Can you try running docker container ls -f 'status=exited' to list exited containers and check if there are containers of your chaincode (you may also try checking if there is at least an image created by running docker images) and if there is any - output its logs?